# How can I load an external page with PHP and replace content on that page?

Tags: php

I'm building a PHP app that allows a user to upload an ad and preview it on specific pages of a specific website. Right now, I'm doing it by taking screenshots of the webpage, removing the ads, and placing my own s. This seems pretty stupid.

What would be the best way to get the contents of a URL and replace code that appears between a certain  on that page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Load the page source into a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) object
- Do a search and replace using [`XPath`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) on the `DOMDocument` object

Example:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.example.com");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$logoImage = $xpath->query("//div[@id='header-logo']//a//img")->item(0);
$logoImage->setAttribute('src', 'http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png');

$logoLink = $xpath->query("//div[@id='header-logo']//a")->item(0);
$logoLink->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com/');

echo $dom->saveHTML();

?>
```

The example loads the source of `example.com` and replaces the logo with `google.com`'s logo and a link to google.

The code does not have any validation but should be pretty easy to modify for your needs :)

Comment: You can actually use [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile](http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtmlfile) with the *http* stream wrapper and skip the `file_get_contents` step entirely.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that while writing the example :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about complete situation that how you would like to perform this action. 
However on base of your question best way is to use Ajax.

Through Ajax pass detail of page you want to display and in php filter page as you want to display and return desired result.

And at the end of Ajax request display your result in particular location.

Even in JavaScript you can filter result as you like returned by Ajax request.

Comment: It all boils down to if you want the work to be done client side or server side, client side might be more work.

Comment: yes nicklas you are right. But when I think about given scenario, it smells like it might be possible that user can upload multiple ads and he would like to review his ads from one location. So just keeping this in my mind I gave my answer in favour of client side. However personally i do not do filtering stuff on client side. I always prepare desired result in php and just use js to display properly

Comment: Don't get me wrong, client side is usually more dynamic and good for the end user, it just requires more work :)

Comment: Yeah, You are 100% right. But what i have been experienced my little working life is, my boss is always in favour of better user experience and he always come back with more expandable solutions. And as a programmer I developed behaviour of keeping open development possibilities for future

Comment: Of course, the time necessary might not always be available, but if it is it's usually worth the time!